# Jumbotron is not consistently static

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My page's jumbotron has an h1,p and an image that is acting as a logo. The h1 and p  have position: sticky, which is something I don't want, but when I remove that style the image shifts downwards and messes with my navbar.

I've tried changing the position: styles for .jumbotron fluid, jumbowords, the img container, but none of that has made the img go back to its normal spot without making h1/p(jumbowords) have a sticky effect.

I've replicated the problem in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kenneth1026/18ocv062/7/

HTML

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="jumbowords">
      <h1 id="Title">K&C Transmissions</h1>
      <p>San Jose, CA</p>
    </div>
    <!--wrapping the img in a container allows us to float the container-->
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    </div>
  </div>



  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a class="hvr-sweep-to-right hvr-wobble-top" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class= "hvr-sweep-to-right hvr-wobble-top" href="aboutUs.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a class= "hvr-sweep-to-right hvr-wobble-top" href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <br>
  <br>
  <br>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron-fluid
{
    margin:0 auto;
    position:static;
    background-color:#f4f8ff;
    height:20em;
    color:#000666;
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;

}



.jumbowords
{
  position:fixed;
 font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-style:italic;
  /*color:#000666;*/
  margin:0 auto;

}



.navbar
{
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#000666;
  /*border-bottom:5px solid #f4f8ff;*/
  border-bottom: 5px solid #f2e319;
  margin-left:0 auto;
  margin-top:0;
  position:static;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li a
{
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size:22px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-left:10px;
  font-style:italic;


}



.navbar-inverse
{
  border-radius:0;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.img-container {
  float: right;
  margin-top:-20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  position:static;

}
```

Comment: Can you better explain what you want all of the elements to do when scrolling?

Comment: When I scroll down, I want the img and words in the jumbotron to stay where they are; not stick to the top of my window view.

Comment: Still need more calrity. The h1 and p are staying where they originally were rendered on scroll. The image is the only thing not staying where it was originally rendered. Are you saying you want the image to stay put on scroll like the h1 and p currently are?

Comment: As you can see in this image(https://ibb.co/9q7nq8r) I scrolled down to the bottom of the window in the jsfiddle. The h1 and p have followed me, and I want them to stay at the top, just like the image. Are we somehow on different fiddles? Just in case, here is the link at where I took that screenshot: https://jsfiddle.net/Kenneth1026/18ocv062/9/

Comment: The h1 and p are not following you. They are not moving! They are stuck to the top and everything else is scrolling up past it.

Comment: I see. I misinterpreted it.

Comment: No problem. So you just want your nav and image to scroll up like the rest of the page? Or you want the navbar + image fixed so you can always see it even when you scroll?

Comment: Scroll up like the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some positioning to (I believe) give you what you want.

Remove fixed position of jumbowords so they scroll with the page.

Instead of floating your image, you can position it to its parent.
 -set the jumbotron's position to relative so you can position its children easily.

```
.jumbotron-fluid { position: relative; }
```

-this way, you can position elements inside it with "absolute" and use the top and right properties to position the image container.

```
.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wa2ynt4c/

Answer (score 0):

Put the src for the image directly in the image container and title below it in its own div. I changed image-container to image-responsive, but use either to your preference.

```
<img class="img-responsive"src="http://yourreallylongurl" />
<div class="img-title">
<h1> K&C Transmissions </h1>
<h3> San Jose, CA </h3>
</div>
```

Assumption is, you have an image-title css. Most likely you do.

I would scrap the Jumbotron parts, and use the image-responsive or image-header class for the image, but I guess that’s to your preference.